# How can I set my pagedown directive to $dirty?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following pagedown directive. How can I set my directive to dirty whenever I change/edit the textarea?

```
app.directive('pagedown', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
var nextId = 0;
var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

converter.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
    return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
        return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
    });
});

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        content: "=",
        modal: '=modal'
    },
    link: function (scope, iElement, attrs) {

        var editorUniqueId;

        if (attrs.id == null) {
            editorUniqueId = nextId++;
        } else {
            editorUniqueId = attrs.id;
        }

        var newElement = $compile(
            '<div>' +
                '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
                    '<div data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<textarea data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '" ng-model="content" >' +
                        '</textarea>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
            '</div>')(scope)
        ;

        iElement.append(newElement);

        var help = angular.isFunction(scope.help) ? scope.help : function () {
            alert("Do you need help?");
        };

        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-" + editorUniqueId, {
            handler: help
        });

        var editorElement = angular.element(document.getElementById("wmd-input-" + editorUniqueId));

        editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            // wire up changes caused by user interaction with the pagedown controls
            // and do within $apply
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.content = editorElement.val();
            });
        });

        editor.run();
    }
}
}]);
```

In HTML:

```
<pagedown class="pagedown-admin"
          modal="ahs.modal"
          content="ahs.modal.data.text"></pagedown>
```

Right now only the textarea is being set to $dirty but not the whole pagedown directive. Can someone please point to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *directive* cannot be `$dirty`, not without manual hacking or the correct element type.

An `input`, `textarea`, `form` can become `$dirty` and will then receive the `ng-dirty` class (so yes, a directive where the element is either of these - the full directive can be $dirty, if that's how one would like to reason about it).

What you could do is to *replace* the directive element with a `form` element, and any manipulation of input controls within said form would set the appropriate $dirty flah / dirty class on the form.

Like so:

```
.directive('', function () {
  return {
    replace: true, 
    template: '<form name="myForm"></form>'
  }
});
```

However, replace [is deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb) *(you can still use it, for now).*

---

Instead, I would suggest you wrap the contents of the `newElement` with a `form` instead of a `div`, and live with the fact that your entire directive template *wont* be marked as `$dirty`.

```
var newElement = $compile(
    '<form name="myForm">' +
        '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
            '<div data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
            '<div>' +
                '<textarea data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '" ng-model="content" >' +
                '</textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
    '</form>')(scope)
;
```

---

#### *Might I ask what the goal of all of this is?*

---

If you were **really** looking to set the directive to `$dirty` (alas, I do not understand *why*) - you could do something like this (with the above changes in mind):

```
 scope.$watch('myForm.$dirty', function (v) {
   attrs.$set('dirty', !!v);
 });
```

You cannot set `$dirty` as an attribute on the containing directive element, as `$dirty` is not a valid attribute name. I believe that's about as close as you will get.

---

### Edit

Based on the comments below, my only conclusion is that you must've somehow forgotten to *name* your form (or ngForm).

Without a name property set, you won't have access to the forms `$dirty` flag in your scope. Classes will be set if you look in the inspector, but the flags will only be available if you expose the form object on your `$scope` (done by naming it).

Try the following:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <pagedown-directive></pagedown-directive>
  <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$dirty"></button>
</form>
```

That should only ever enable the button if `myForm.$dirty` is `true`. Isolate scopes don't *break* the flow of things inside a form from my experience/what I can see, so you should be covered there.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tupugakanu/1/edit?html,js,output) showcasing how it would work.

Comment: thank you for the long answer. So the scenario is I have a form with buttons and more than 1 pagedown directive inside. Some of my buttons are set to be enable only if the form is not $pristine.

Comment: Okay. So there's a wrapping form with these pagedown directives inside them, and you would like for the pagedown directive(s) to set the $dirty state of the container form, so as to disable some buttons living next to the pagedown directives. Is that the correct assumption?

Comment: See my latest edit for a suggestion on how to troubleshoot/fix the issue.

Comment: @Sophia Did you have any luck with the suggested changes?